# Django Admin template override

Tags: python, django, templates

I am following the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.0/intro/tutorial07/) on django website to create my first django app.

Now I am stuck trying to override Django Admin template.

My project directory is this:

[image]

First I tried creating a new admin template in the surveys app. It works.

Then, I tried with the override function. For this I created at `surveys/admin.py` the following code:

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy


class SurveysAdminSite(AdminSite):
    site_header = ugettext_lazy('Test administration')

surveys_admin_site = SurveysAdminSite()
```

And add to `computationalMarketing/urls.py` the following:

```
from .admin import surveys_admin_site

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', surveys_admin_site.urls, name='admin'),
]
```

It doesn't work, so I search, and tried something different. Add this same previous code to `surveys/urls.py`. Neither works. Then I rollback the changes to save the code to `computationalMarketing/urls.py`, but this time I changed the code from `surveys/admin.py` to `computationalMarketing/admin.py` (in fact I created the file because it doesn't exists.

It works and now I see the site header that I want, but I get `You don't have permission to edit anything.` I have seen that is something related with superuser creation, but until now I was able to admin my `surveys app` without problem, so I believe in some solution related with override properly the `admin.py` at `surveys app`

Does anybody knows why this does not works as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the complete admin site. You may want to override only specific templates and keep using the default admin site.

A first approach to solve your problem is to add models to your admin site:

`surveys/admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy
from surveys.models import OneModel, OtherModel

class SurveysAdminSite(AdminSite):
    site_header = ugettext_lazy('Test administration')

surveys_admin_site = SurveysAdminSite()

surveys_admin_site.register(OneModel)
surveys_admin_site.register(OtherModel)
```

And maybe use [ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) objects to add advanced behavior.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @alfonso.kim for your answer. If I am not wrong your code goes to computationalMarketing/admin.py but it doesn't work. I also tried in surveys/admin.py and neither works.

Seems like surveys.model is an unresolved reference in both files.

Comment: It goes in `surveys/admin.py`. Try `from .models import ...`

Comment: what about surveys/urls.py and computationalMarketing/urls.py?

Comment: maybe it is an overkill to override all the admin site. Try to register some models first.